# How to overwrite string in a file

Tags: python

I am writing a code that replaces the words ADJECTIVE, NOUN and VERB form a file named text.txt with words from a users input but the code does not work as I want it to.

the text from the file is:
The ADJECTIVE walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.

The inputs:

```
panda

forest

ate

cat
```

The output as it should be:

```
The panda walked to the forest and then ate. A nearby cat was
unaffected by these events.
```

The real output of the code:

```
The ADJECTIVE walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.The panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.The ADJECTIVE walked to the forest and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.The ADJECTIVE walked to the NOUN and then ate. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.The ADJECTIVE walked to the cat and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.
```

my code:

```py
import re

with open("text.txt", "r+") as f:
    text = f.read()
    matches = re.findall(r"ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB", text)
    print(matches)
    for i in matches:
        new_text = text.replace(
            i, input(f"What would you like to replace the {i} with: "), 1
        )
        f.write(new_text)
```

Comment: You have somehow managed to lose all indentation in the code you posted here - which in the case of Python, makes the code *utterly meaningless*.  You need to correct that before we can say anything about what's going wrong in the code.

Comment: [formatting code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: you're making all the replacements to the original text. So each time through the loop you start fresh with the original text, you don't combine all the replacements. Get rid of the `new_text` variable, and use `text = text.replace(...)`

Comment: Not really relevant to the code, but "panda" is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: @slothrop why did you have to point out? I'll spend the rest of the day trying to use "panda" as an adjective :)

Comment: @Friedrich Fair point, I mean you can talk about "panda eyes" :) So really, I should have said that *in OP's example sentence*, "panda" is a noun.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the correct format of the code you provided is this one:

```
import re
with open('text.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    matches = re.findall(r'ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB', text)
    print(matches)
    for i in matches:
        new_text = text.replace(i, input(f'What would you like to replace the {i} with: ' ), 1)
        f.write(new_text)
```

So, what you're currently doing is writing the whole phrase with the latest change into the file on each iteration inside the for loop. What you may want is to first, do the writing at the very end of your program and outside of your loop.

```
import re
with open('text.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    matches = re.findall(r'ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB', text)
    print(matches)
    new_text = text
    for i in matches:
        new_text = new_text.replace(i, input(f'What would you like to replace the {i} with: ' ), 1)
    f.write(new_text)
```

As you can see here I'm writing at the very end of the program in order to do it only once, here you may or may not want to add a new line before writing to the file the new content. Also you may have noticed that I added a new line of code, so, in order to persist the changes you're getting by the input, you need to modify the variable new_text and do the replace on top of the previous changes made by the previous inputs. With this you'll get the desired output:

> The panda walked to the forest and then ate. A nearby cat was unaffected by these events.

Hope I didn't overcomplicated this explanation.

Comment: This is helpful thank you but why are you using: 

`new_text = text`

Can't I just use the variable text and
`text = text.replace(i, input(f'What would you like to replace the {i} with: ' ), 1)
    f.write(new_text)`

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish, if you don't want to use your "template" of "The ADJECTIVE walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events." for anything else then it's okay to use the variable as you mention, if you want to keep using that "template" to generate more phrases like that it would be better to have a different variable to overwrite your changes.